# ElasticSearch handling Rails route params with nested objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, routes, searchkick

We have a Rails search route which can accept nested objects that should map to ElasticSearch operators.

For example:

```
{
  name: "John",
  age: {
    {gte: 20}
  }
}
```

The problem is that the SearchKick library throws an error when the Rails route params look like the following:

```
{"name"=>["Sam Terrick", "John Terrick"], "age"=>{"gte"=>"20"}}
```

The Searchkick library maps through these filters and does a case comparison for `:gte`, but the hash rocket keys do not match. ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess doesn't get the job done.

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/master/lib/searchkick/query.rb

Is there an elegant way to handle this transformation of nested objects from the route params without having to check if each param is a Hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you could make use of the Rails [`Hash.html#method-i-deep_transform_keys`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#deep_transform_keys):

```
params = {"name"=>["Sam Terrick", "John Terrick"], "age"=>{"gte"=>"20"}}
p params.deep_transform_keys(&:to_sym)
# {:name=>["Sam Terrick", "John Terrick"], :age=>{:gte=>"20"}}
```

But Rails also implements other handy method, more accurate in this case, [`Hash.html#deep_symbolize_keys`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_symbolize_keys):

```
p params.deep_symbolize_keys
# # {:name=>["Sam Terrick", "John Terrick"], :age=>{:gte=>"20"}}
```

Same result.